# Adding bindable property to a UserControl

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

### Purpose

The purpose of the control is to display 12 buttons in the form 6x2 grid. Clicking on a button should set VM's `ActiveLayer` property to the clicked button's index (1 through 12). UserControl should highlight current layer by changing the button's `Background` to `SkyBlue`.

### Steps

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Added a `DependencyProperty` named `ActiveLayer` to my UserControl. `PropertyChangedCallBack` of this dependency property updates button's `Background` (see at the bottom).
2. Added a `Grid` (6 cols, 2 rows) and 12 `Button` controls in it, in XAML. Button's `Tag` property is set to their index, i.e. 1 through 12. All buttons are attached to the same event handler `Button_Click`, which has the following simple body:

   `SetValue(ActiveLayerProperty, CInt(DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag))`
3. In my Window, where the UserControl is used, I have the following XAML:

   `<local:LayerSelector ActiveLayer="{Binding ActiveDrawing.ActiveLayer}" />`

Here is `PropertyChangedCallBack` handler:

```
Sub(sender As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
  Dim Ctl = DirectCast(sender, LayerSelector)
  Dim WH = New SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.White)
  For i = 0 To 11
    DirectCast(Ctl.FindName("btn" + i.ToString()), Button).Background = WH
  Next

  DirectCast(Ctl.FindName("btn" + e.NewValue.ToString()), Button).Background = New SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.SkyBlue)
End Sub
```

### Problem

The above setup doesn't appear to change my VM's `ActiveLayer` property. Button Background and UserControl's `ActiveLayer` property seem to be updated though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the `DataContext` for your `UserControl`, which is correct, however, binding to a Dependency Property is slightly different in this scenario. You need to bind directly to the `UserControl` element.

You can use a `RelativeSource` binding, like this:

```
ActiveLayer="{Binding ActiveDrawing.ActiveLayer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

Or, give your `UserControl` and `x:Name` and use the following:

```
ActiveLayer="{Binding ActiveDrawing.ActiveLayer, ElementName=yourUserControlName}"
```

Comment: I didn't expect any of these to work, but I gave them a go and found that they indeed do not work. Why are you setting `ActiveDrawing.ActiveLayer` on the UserControl? My UserControl does not have any such property. `ActiveDrawing.ActiveLayer` is a property of my Window's DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary ViewModel for the Buttons, and set and have a boolean property (IsActive).

In the Main ViewModel create a collection of ViewModels and set the DataContext on each button to a different indexed ViewModel in the collection.

When the button is clicked you can set the IsActive property on the clicked button to true and all the other buttons to False.
Bind the BackgroundColor on each button to the IsActive property, and use a IValueConverter to convert the boolean value to a background color.

To do this you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the button ViewModel.